# Assign the same rank to student with the same scores

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm assigning ranks to students based on their scores but I encountered a problem where if two or more students have the same scores they are given different ranks.

E.G John, Rita, and Mary scored 76. John is 1st, Rita is 2nd, and Mary is 3rd.

1. John ==> 76
2. Rita ==> 76
3. Mary ==> 76
4. Bukky ==>74

I want three of them to have the rank as 1st.

1. John ==> 76
2. Rita ==> 76
3. Mary ==> 76
4. Bukky ==>74

```php
public function getStudentpositionOnlyClass($student_id, $class_id, $terms)
{
    $array_product = array();

    if ($class_id == 22 || $class_id == 23) {
        if ($terms == 'f') {
            $totField = 'ft_tot_score';
            $table = 'ftscores_rn';
        } elseif ($terms == 'm') {
            $totField = 'mt_tot_score';
            $table = 'mtscores_rn';
        } elseif ($terms == 's') {
            $totField = 'tot_score';
            $table = 'scores_rn';
        } elseif ($terms == 'h') {
            $totField = 'h_tot_score';
            $table = 'hscores_rn';
        }
    } else {
        if ($terms == 'f') {
            $totField = 'ft_tot_score';
            $table = 'ftscores_primary';
        } elseif ($terms == 'm') {
            $totField = 'mt_tot_score';
            $table = 'mtscores_primary';
        } elseif ($terms == 's') {
            $totField = 'tot_score';
            $table = 'scores_primary';
        } elseif ($terms == 'h') {
            $totField = 'h_tot_score';
            $table = 'hscores_primary';
        }
    }

    $fail = 0;
    $pass = 0;

    $resultlist = $this->student_model->fullSearchByClass($class_id);

    foreach ($resultlist->result_array() as $key => $stdName) {
        $idd = $key + 1;
        $mId[$idd] = $stdName['pstudent_id'];

        $totalSubMarks = $this->db->query(
            "SELECT  mts.subject_id
                     FROM " . $table . " mts
                     LEFT JOIN subjects sub ON(sub.id=mts.subject_id)
                     WHERE class_id=" . $class_id .
            " AND mts.subject_id IS NOT NULL
                     GROUP BY mts.subject_id ORDER BY sub.name");
        $gtotal = 0;
        $totSubjects = 0;

        foreach ($totalSubMarks->result_array() as $tmrow) {

            $totalMarks = $this->student_model->getTotalMarksForStudnets($tmrow['subject_id'],
                $stdName['pstudent_id'], $table, $totField);
            // //// set mtotalmark

            $gtotal = $gtotal + $totalMarks;
            // //// set mgtotal
            $mGTotal[$idd] = $gtotal;

            if ($totalMarks != 0) {
                $totSubjects = $totSubjects + 1;
            }
            // //// set mAvg
            if ($totSubjects != 0) {
                $mAvg[$idd] = round($gtotal / $totSubjects, 1);
            } else {
                $mAvg[$idd] = 0;
            }
        }

        // /////////
        if ($totSubjects != 0) {
            $percentage = ($gtotal / $totSubjects);
        }
        if ($percentage >= 0 && $percentage <= 39.99) {
            $fail = $fail + 1;
        } else {
            $pass = $pass + 1;
        }
    }

    foreach ($mAvg as $dd => $val) {
        // if pure numbers store in nums array
        if (! is_nan($val)) {
            $nums[$dd] = $val;
        }
    }
    arsort($nums);

    $id = 1;
    foreach ($nums as $kk => $av) {

        foreach ($totalSubMarks->result_array() as $tmrow) {
            $totalMarks = $this->student_model->getTotalMarksForStudnets($tmrow['subject_id'], $mId[$kk], $table,
                $totField);
        }

        if ($student_id == $mId[$kk]) {
            return $id;
        }
        // $array_product['student'.$mId[$kk]]= $id;
        $id += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: more like 1,1,1,2.

Comment: You are not using placeholders in your `query()` call.

Comment: Ah "dense rank" then.  Here is a good read: https://mattmazur.com/2017/03/26/exploring-ranking-techniques-in-mysql/

Comment: Iterated calls to model methods calling the database are a bad idea.

Comment: Am I looking at a controller method?  `$totSubjects = $totSubjects + 1;` is more simply expressed as `++$totSubjects;`

Comment: This was done in the model

Comment: That's good.  Just checking.  I'll be honest, I am struggling to review your code because you have poor code tabbing and unintuitive variable naming.

Comment: I'm still learning, and I must admit I'm quite stuck

Comment: You need to memorize the previous score as you iterate and keep updating the previous score.  You should only increment the rank variable if the current score is different from the previous score.

Comment: I don't understand why `$totalSubMarks` is being declared over and over,  but the values passed into it never change.  Did I miss something?

Comment: What variable holds your score/position?

Answer (score 0):

As mickmackusa stated in his comment you have to memorize the previous score and only increment the rank if the score has changed. As you already order your results we can assume a score change between 2 iterations is always a decrease.

Your variable names are *very* unintuitive. So maybe my code changes are in the wrong place but you shoud understand the concept. I assume that `$totSubjects` is that score.

Try not to shorten a variable's name too much because you have *no benifit* but loose that important information on what it is. At least comment a variable assignment if its unclear what the variable holds of.

---

Change your loop like this:

```
$previousScore = null;    // added THIS
foreach ($totalSubMarks->result_array() as $tmrow) {

        $totalMarks = $this->student_model->getTotalMarksForStudnets($tmrow['subject_id'],
            $stdName['pstudent_id'], $table, $totField);
        // set mtotalmark

        $gtotal = $gtotal + $totalMarks;
        // set mgtotal
        $mGTotal[$idd] = $gtotal;

        if ($totalMarks != 0) {
            if($previousScore != $totalMarks) {    // added THIS
                $totSubjects = $totSubjects + 1;
            } else {                               // added THIS
                $totSubjects = $totSubjects;       // keep rank without incrementing
            }
        }
        $previousScore = $totalMarks;       // added THIS

        // set mAvg
        if ($totSubjects != 0) {
            $mAvg[$idd] = round($gtotal / $totSubjects, 1);
        } else {
            $mAvg[$idd] = 0;
        }
    }
```

In case  `$gtotal` or any of the other mystic variables ;) is holding the score then try to modify my given code changes to `$gtotal`. Shouldn't be too hard. In that case just add a comment so I can change my answer that it's actualy correct.

Hope that helps!